# newcommand putting strange space before text

Tags: spacing, macros

I'm trying to do the usual "make a worksheet with blank spaces", and I need blanks longer than the text which will eventually fill them (so that students can write in answers by hand). Unfortunately, my command "blank" prints a strange amount of space before evaluating in the text. If I just insert the same command in the body, it evaluates normally.

```
    \documentclass[]{article}
    \newlength\mylen
    \newlength\fieldlen
    \newcommand\blank[1]{%
       \settowidth\mylen{#1}
       \settowidth\fieldlen{0}
       \addtolength\fieldlen{\mylen}
       \addtolength\fieldlen{\mylen}
       \underline{\makebox[\fieldlen]{}}    %comment this line and uncomment next line to hide answers
       %\underline{\makebox[\fieldlen]{#1}} %comment this line and uncomment previous line to show answers
    }
    \begin{document}

Using the macro, I get the following:

We find that $G<$\blank{$G_1$}.

There's an extra space before the underline. 

I want it to look like:

We find that $G<$\underline{\makebox[\fieldlen]{}}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usage of the macros `\settowidth` and `\addtolength` is missing a `%` at the end, so 4 missing `%` will lead to one additional space character each.

As well there is a missing `%` after `\underline`, so the `.` is shifted to the right.

```
  \documentclass[]{article}
  \newlength\mylen
  \newlength\fieldlen
  \newcommand\blank[1]{%
    \settowidth{\mylen}{#1}%
    \settowidth{\fieldlen}{0}%
    \addtolength{\fieldlen}{\mylen}%
    \addtolength{\fieldlen}{\mylen}%
    \underline{\makebox[\fieldlen]{}}%    %comment this line and uncomment next line to hide answers
    % \underline{\makebox[\fieldlen]{#1}} %comment this line and uncomment previous line to show answers
  }
  \begin{document}

Using the macro, I get the following:

We find that $G<$\blank{$G_1$}.

There's an extra space before the underline. 

I want it to look like:

We find that $G<$\underline{\makebox[\fieldlen]{}}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! By the way, how do you get the Latex to print in the post like that?

Comment: @richbenp: Make a screenshot of the output in your PDF viewer and save it as `.jpg` or `.png` file. There is no way to cause `TeX.SE` to compile and display the output

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: $G<{}$ would look better, I think.

Comment: @Bernard: That was not the issue, however

Comment: I will happily accept the answer ... although I confess ignorance about how to do so!

Comment: @richbenp: Follow the instructions here: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1852/how-do-you-accept-an-answer